# android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException - cursor was closed

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

The DB cursor throws the exception saying the cursor was open, thou it is closed each time. Is it the return statement messing this up?

```
public long getValue() {

        long val = 0;

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            if (db != null) {
                cursor = db.query(*****);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(****));
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Getting the below exception:

```
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=1 (# cursors opened by this proc=1)
```

Comment: You just have too much data in your cursor, such as binary content like image data.

Comment: but then why it says open cursor ? Open cursor as fares I know is that previous cursor is open